# JBoss not releasing memory

Tags: java, memory-management, jboss, visualvm

I am running a Java application in JBoss which periodically undertakes a memory-intensive task. The amount of memory used by org.jboss.Main rises during this time, but does not fall once the task is completed. 
I've been profiling the process using VisualVM and have forced a garbage collection. The memory used by org.jboss.Main remains at about 1GB. The basic info of the heap dump is as follows.

```
Total bytes: 53,795,695
Total classes: 5,696
Total instances: 732,292
Classloaders: 324
GC roots: 2,540
Number of objects pending for finalization: 0
```

I've also looked at the classes using the memory and found that char[] accounts for most of the memory.

Could anyone tell me why VisualVM shows 20 times less memory being used by JBoss than my activity monitor? And if anyone could provide any advice or directions to further reading on  how to get JBoss to release memory after the job is complete that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VisualVM is showing the size of the heap after a Full GC.  This is the amount of data you can use before the heap has to grow.

The heap dump is showing you how much of the heap is used at present.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter. Did you mean 'Activity monitor is showing the size of the heap after a Full GC.' So I could use up to 1GB before the heap needs to get larger? And does that mean that there was a point at which a heap dump would show something like "Total bytes: 1,000,000,000"

Comment: There was a point when the heap grew due to the rate you were allocating objects.  The GC tries to predict what the size might need to be, and so it may not have used all 1 GB.  Note: each region, Eden, survivor and tenured spaces are sized independently.  I expect the Eden to be full at some point, the survivors try to be 50% full by default and the tenured might only be 40% full at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll also be doing a little more reading on memory regions. One last question: I notice that the memory in Activity Monitor does fluctuate over time, but according to this [thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/202451/Performance/java/JVM-memory-releasing) it should only rise and not fall. Why can I see it fluctuating?

Comment: Most likely you are look at the amount used which usually follows a swap tooth pattern, not the amount reserved which typically only goes up (but can be returned to the OS, so it can go down.  Exactly how and when it returns memory to the OS is not clear to me)

Comment: BTW Just connecting the VisualVM to a JVM will cause it to display a saw tooth pattern.  VisualVM creates quite a bit of garbage to collect its information so you can see the heap working away in an otherwise idle process.  You can reduce this by reducing the pooling rate.